# Stacking view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iPhone development and not even sure if I do it right. I basically want to separate my screen into multiple regions.

I am currently trying to stack view controllers inside each other like div boxes on HTML (please correct me if its not the way how it is supposed to be done)

Column is inherited from `UIViewController`:

```
  Column *column = [Column new];
```

Tells me something about incompatible pointers.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do that.

You **can** use multiple View Controllers in a single screen but, typically for simple apps, just use a single View Controller per screen.

By all means stack UIViews like div boxes but just use one View Controller.

Comment: Thanks! Just did not know better. Now i do!

Answer (score 0):

```
Column *column = [[Colulmn alloc] init];
```

And have a look at View Containers in IB. They are designed for subviews that have their own view controller. If it is that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for mulitple scrollable regions in an iPad app, take a look at the Master-Detail project template in Xcode, which uses UISplitViewController.